# Não consigo encontrar solução para o Erro "java.lang.NullPointerException" - Android Studio

Tags: java, android

Aparece o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.Object.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                  at novapetbeta.platypus.com.novapetbeta.Principal$6.onChildAdded(Principal.java:185)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdri.zza(Unknown Source:33)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdwu.zzbvb(Unknown Source:2)
                  at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzdxa.run(Unknown Source:65)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Esse é o código que está aparecendo o erro.

```
public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists() && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("Meh").hasChild(atualUID) && !dataSnapshot.child("connections").child("Gostei").hasChild(atualUID)){
                String ImagemPerfilURL = "default";
                if (!dataSnapshot.child("ImagemPerfilURL").getValue().equals("default")){
                    ImagemPerfilURL = dataSnapshot.child("ImagemPerfilURL").getValue().toString();
                }
```

Eu sou nova em desenvolvimento mobile e não estou conseguindo resolver isso. 
Agradeço pela ajuda.

Comment: Observando a mensagem de erro vemos que `Attempt to invoke virtual method '...equals...' on a null object reference` => "Tentou executar `equals` sobre algo que é `null`". Certamente se refere a esta linha `dataSnapshot.child("ImagemPerfilURL").getValue().equals("default")` em que `dataSnapshot.child("ImagemPerfilURL").getValue()` deve estar a trazer `null`. Comece por ai, tentando perceber o que essa parte dá como valor e porquê. Pode e deve sempre fazer *Debug* à aplicação e usar o *LogCat* para tentar extrair o máximo de informação e perceber que valores tem em cada parte do código

Comment: `NullPointerException` é porque `dataSnapshot.child("ImagemPerfilURL").getValue()` está `null` ou sem vazio, você está fazendo um equals de uma variável vazia, verifique o caminho do JSON, pode ser isso

Answer (score 1):

Você utilizou o método `equals` quando o `dataSnapshot.child("ImagemPerfilURL").getValue()` é nulo.

Se o child `"ImagemPerfilURL"` não pode ser nulo, então **esse** é o real problema, sendo o `NullPointerException` apenas resultado disso.